# Url opening in Web browser instead of taskpane

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have developed an excel custom function. I have added the helpurl in the custom function. When I click on that function it opens the URL in the web browser. I want to open that URL in the excel task pane. I am getting problems with that. Here is my function. How can I open that URL in the task pane only or in the help section of Microsoft?

```
 /**
     * Multiply By 10.
     * @customfunction
     * @helpurl https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html
     * @param count First number.
     * @returns {number} The multiply by ten.
     */
    async function count(count) {
      return count * 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for opening a task pane programmatically. But you can bind the task pane to a document, so it could be opened automatically with a document. Read more about that in the [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) article.

You can access the task pane for loading a web page from your custom function if the shared runtime is used in the add-in, see [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) for more information.

Finally, keep in mind that feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .